# sql server : join query multiple query

Tags: sql, sql-server

DEFECT
25-10-2016
25-10-2016
26-10-2016

PRODUCTION
25-10-2016
26-10-2016
26-10-2016
26-10-2016

how can i write query for below OUTPUT...

OUTPUT          D_COUNT        P_COUNT
25-10-2016            2                               1
26-10-2016            1                               3

Please help me

I tried this:

```
Select 
    QD.defect_time, 
    Count(OD.start_time) as production_count, 
    Count(QD.defect_time) as defect_count 
from QUALITY_DEFECT_1 QD 
JOIN ORDER_DETAILS OD ON QD.order_id = OD.order_id 
group by QD.defect_time
```

Comment: What have you tried? Could you provide your existing attemps?

Comment: I want to write sql query which give me mentioned output:

Comment: Sure, but what have you tried already? We will help you but we're not here to code for you.

Comment: i tried with : Select QD.defect_time,
 Count(OD.start_time) as production_count,
    Count(QD.defect_time) as defect_count
    from QUALITY_DEFECT_1 QD JOIN ORDER_DETAILS OD ON QD.order_id = OD.order_id
 group by QD.defect_time

Answer (score 0):

You can start from something like this:

```
SELECT A.COL1, B.D_COUNT, C.P_COUNT
FROM
(SELECT DISTINCT DEF_COL AS COL1 FROM DEFECT
 UNION 
 SELECT DISTINCT PROD_COL FROM PRODUCTION 
) A
LEFT JOIN (SELECT DEF_COL, COUNT(*) AS D_COUNT FROM DEFECT GROUP BY DEF_COL) B ON A.COL1 = B.DEF_COL
LEFT JOIN (SELECT PROD_COL, COUNT(*) AS P_COUNT FROM PROUCTION GROUP BY PROD_COL) C ON A.COL1 = C.PROD_COL
```

Answer (score 0):

You need `Full Outer Join`

```
SELECT COALESCE(d.dates, p.dates),
       d.cnt ,
       p.cnt 
FROM   (SELECT dates,Count(dates) cnt
        FROM   DEFECT
        GROUP  BY dates) d
       FULL OUTER JOIN (SELECT dates,Count(dates) cnt
                        FROM   PRODUCTION
                        GROUP  BY dates) p
                    ON d.dates = p.dates
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT

ISNULL(DEFECT.D_OUTPUT, PRODUCTION.D_OUTPUT) AS D_OUTPUT
,ISNULL(DEFECT.D_COUNT,0)               AS D_COUNT
,ISNULL(PRODUCTION.P_COUNT,0)           AS P_COUNT

FROM
(

SELECT 
DateD     AS D_OUTPUT
,COUNT(*) AS D_COUNT
FROM DEFECT
GROUP BY DateD

) DEFECT

FULL JOIN
(

SELECT 
DateP     AS D_OUTPUT
,COUNT(*) AS P_COUNT
FROM PRODUCTION
GROUP BY DateP

) PRODUCTION ON PRODUCTION.D_OUTPUT =  DEFECT.D_OUTPUT
```

I hope it will work for you.

Comment: can we write it without subquery??

Answer (score 0):

Not understood the question fully but If DEFECT and PRODUCTION different tables then you can try ----

```
select PRODUCTION As OUTPUT,count(*) P_COUNT from PRODUCTION
group by PRODUCTION


select DEFECT As OUTPUT,count(*) D_COUNT from DEFECT
group by DEFECT
```

Answer (score 0):

```
;With DEFECT(DEFECT_Date)
AS
(
SELECT '25-10-2016' Union all
SELECT '25-10-2016' Union all
SELECT '26-10-2016' 
)
,PRODUCTION (PRODUCTION_Date)
AS
(
SELECT '25-10-2016' UNION ALL
SELECT '26-10-2016' UNION ALL
SELECT '26-10-2016' UNION ALL
SELECT '26-10-2016' 
)
,CTe3
AS
(
SELECT DISTINCT DEFECT_Date
    ,COUNT(DEFECT_Date) OVER (
        PARTITION BY DEFECT_Date ORDER BY DEFECT_Date
        ) AS D_COUNT
    ,NULL AS P_COUNT
FROM DEFECT D

UNION ALL

SELECT DISTINCT PRODUCTION_Date
    ,NULL
    ,COUNT(PRODUCTION_Date) OVER (
        PARTITION BY PRODUCTION_Date ORDER BY PRODUCTION_Date
        ) AS P_COUNT
FROM PRODUCTION D )
    ,FINAL AS (
        SELECT DEFECT_Date
            ,D_COUNT
        FROM CTe3
        WHERE D_COUNT IS NOT NULL
        )

SELECT C.DEFECT_Date
      ,F.D_COUNT
      ,c.P_COUNT

FROM CTe3 c
FULL JOIN FINAL F ON C.DEFECT_Date = F.DEFECT_Date
WHERE P_COUNT IS NOT NULL
```

OutPut

```
DEFECT_Date   D_COUNT   P_COUNT
-----------------------------
25-10-2016      2        1
26-10-2016      1        3
```